# Skyrim freezes when loading on Xbox 360?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I have been playing Skyrim for some time now but now, every time I try to load any of my saves it takes me to the loading screen, then freezes before the tip can even fade out! It's always the first tip that it freezes on.

This also sometimes happens when I'm just playing the game. I'll just be doing something then, BAM! My game freezes.

I let my Xbox cool down but that did nothing. I also tried deleting a bunch of my save files but that didn't work either. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: My first guess would be the disk is scratched. Can you either test that disk on a different Xbox or a different copy of Skyrim on your Xbox?

Answer (score 1):

When that happens to me, all I have to do is wait about 5 minutes. If that doesn't work then the game disk could be scratched.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me. From what I have determined, it was in my case, hard drive failure. You will especially notice these issues when you load a save or if it attempts to load DLC / installed content.

It is a common issue with hard drives in general. Over time, especially if used a lot over a short period, they can suffer wear and tear and simply fail. I work in an electronics store in Australia.. all the major suppliers for portable harddrives issue replacement on the spot of this happens, as it is cheaper then fixing it.

Unfortunetly, if this is the case, it means you will be on the look out to replace your hard drive. You will likely also lose your save. Might be worth seeing i you can move the save file to a USB or the cloud from your xbox, or even if you can try a different console.

Comment: note: I use to think my game was scratched due to replicating the same expected behavior as a scratched game. When I got a new 360 I found my game actually did work, but when I chucked in the old hard drive to play my character the issues came back.

Answer (score 0):

You might have a bad disk. Exchange it for a new one, but don't worry, you can back to your saves since all the saves aren't stored on the disk but on the cache. Otherwise clear the cache if that doesn't work. Another solution is [Spoiler]:

> Delete all the autosaves in the game, and turn autosaving off so you can play normally.

If freezing still occurs, it's the xbox.